# Error when writing to serializable file

Tags: java, serializable

I'm programming a simple Java gmail client to finish my A level project.
When the following section of code runs I always get an error. 
I can't find out why the error is there.

```
public static void save(List<user> u3){
    try {

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("users.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(u3);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Added due to suggestion of commentor
    }   
}
```

The error is:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: user
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>       at main.saveu(main.java:65)
>       at main.main(main.java:42)
>       at __SHELL12.run(__SHELL12.java:6)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)

Comment: Does the user class implement Serializable?

Comment: The main class or the user class? neither of them implement serializable

Comment: You should read up on how to [serialize objects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) in Java

Comment: Thanks so much Tezra im not so familiar with the serializable class and I kinda overlooked some stuff thanks for the link and thanks to everybody else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class "User" does not implement Serializable.
Serializable is mostly a tagging interface. You do not need to do anything to implement it. Simply declaring that your class implements it is enough.

```
class User implements Serializable{
    // your existing code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the official [documentation of JEE7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html):

*Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface*

So you need just to implement the `Serializable` interface.

```
class User implements Serializable {
//Staff
}
```